# PHP - Using some sort of loop to ask another form

Tags: php

I've got this so far:

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
$in = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
?>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>ID:</th>
    <th>Item:</th>
    <th>Quantity:</th>
    <th>Sell</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$ID = 0;


foreach (explode(";", $in) as $element) {
        $ID = $ID + 1;
        $element = trim($element);
        if (strpos($element, " ") !== false ) {
                list($car, $number) = explode(" ", $element);
                $Form = "<form method = 'post'> <br> <input type ='submit' name = '$ID' value = 'Sell!' <br> </form>";
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $ID; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $car; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $number; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $Form; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php


        }

}

echo "</table>";
```

What I was wondering was two things:
1. How can I target every single button as it could range from 1 to 100+ I presume it would use some sort of loop? Not sure how it would work though

Comment: it'sverydifficulttounderstandyouwhenyouwriteeverythinginonelongrunonsentence....

Comment: @Pamblam Sorry. I'll edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: here's a tip though: anything to do with clicking on anything will be javascript related, not PHP. PHP don't know anything about clicks.

Comment: @Pamblam Thanks, I'll quickly go look at some sort of example.

Answer (score 0):

First, you've got a typo, you didn't close the button tag here:

```
$Form = "<form method = 'post'> <br> <input type ='submit' name = '$ID' value = 'Sell!' /><br> </form>";
// here .................................................................................^
```

Second, as I mentioned in the comments, clicking is going to handled by Javascript as PHP runs on the server and has nothing to do with the user's actions.

You can do that with jQuery pretty easily, for example:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("do stuff!");
});
```

There are tonnes of tutorials on event handling with Javascript, it's a bit too broad to answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the typo, and looking upon Jquery/JS I cant see how I could define every single click, for example the button could be named from 1 to 100+

Comment: The jquery code i gave will apply to all submit buttons. It would be better to use a classname as a selector, but a loop is not nessesary